# how can i hide my own function definition i.e.function m-file in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I've created my own function definition i.e. function m-file of for my final year project.. now I want to hide that function definition. is there any way for doing it in matlab?
I want that this function m-file should become a part of my matlab compiler directories so that when I call that function from any m-file, it is called and executed, but it's function definition should not be visible to anyone.. actually I want to hide that function definition from my advisor and project evaluation committee.. I don't want that they should get any hint about that function definition... someone said it to me,"convert your m-file to c or c++ code and then add it to matlab directory. your function definition will get hide, and will also be executed when called."
But I don't know how to do it? can anyone help me in doing it? I'm using matlab 7.9.0 (R2009b)
please do help me, if anyone knows anything about it.. :)

Comment: There is a built in function obfuscator, `pcode` [(link)](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html) which you could use. Then adding the folder containing the pcode to the matlab path (or adding the pcode file to a folder on the path), will make it accessible from any other function (so long as it is not shadowed)... the conversion to c or c++ (or just conversion directly to mex) would require additional toolboxes, which you may or may not have access to.

Comment: As the code is to be shared with others, if you were to use [`mex`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) (or [`coder`](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/) in newer versions of Matlab) and compile to C/C++, you might also need to compile for multiple platforms, e.g., [Mac Intel 64, AMD 64, Windows Intel 32 and 64](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mexext.html). Using `pcode` is much more straightforward.

Comment: +1 I did not think of that more obvious reason to favour `pcode`... (also converted my comment to answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are really two parts here

1. 'Hide' function definition
2. Have access to a function from within a m-file

Actually there is a third I will not address or discuss further than the next line
 3. Why would you hide work for a final year project from your advisor & evaluation committee

---

### 1) 'Hide' function definition

There is a built in function obfuscator called `pcode` [(documentation)](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html)

this can be used directly on a function m-file and will create a copy of the function in the current directory with the file extension `.p` in which the code is 'hidden'.

Usage

```
pcode(foo) % foo.m is your function
```

---

### 2) Access to the function

The `.p` file will be available to any function so long as it is on the Matlab path.
So simply add a folder containing the .p file to the Matlab path.

There are a few ways to do this I would personally use [`addpath`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html)

(alternative add the `.p` file to a folder already on the path)